# Is there any row number alternative like SQL in python?

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find the sum of the values with in the group but the problem is I need to select only the 3 possible highest values with in the group and then sum those values for each group.
I have a data frame like this:

```
group  amount
   x      12
   x     345
   x       3
   y       1
   y      45
   z      14
   x       4
   x      52
   y      54
   z      23
   z     235
   z      21
   y      57
   y       3
   z      87
```

IN SQL I can use query like this:

select group, sum(amount) total from ( select group, amount, row_number() over(partition by group order by amount desc) rownum from tbla) z 
where z.rownum between 1 and 3 
group by group

Outcome which I want  before doing group by:

```
  group  amount
   x      12
   x     345
   y      45
   x      52
   y      54
   z      23
   z     235
   y      57
   z      87
```

Based on this Outcome I would like go get the sum of each group

***Final Outcome***

```
    Group    Amount
    X         409
    Y         156
    Z         345
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to **@ScottBoston** I looked further and think we can use `nth()` instead of `head()` to make use of `sum(level=0)`. Another alternative would be to `set_index()` before instead of the old solution where I used groupby twice. Anyway, in order of speed, quickest first:

```
dfout = (df.sort_values(by='amount', ascending=False)
         .groupby('group')
         .head(3)
         .set_index('group')
         .sum(level=0)
         .reset_index())
```

**or**

```
dfout = (df.sort_values(by='amount', ascending=False)
         .groupby('group')
         .nth([0,1,2])
         .sum(level=0)
         .reset_index())
```

**or**

```
dfout = (df.groupby('group')
         .apply(lambda x: x['amount'].sort_values(ascending=False).head(3).sum())
         .rename('amount')
         .reset_index())
```

**or** a two-step approach to get your temp dataframe as shown in the question:

```
mid = df.sort_values(by='amount', ascending=False).groupby('group').head(3).sort_index()
final = mid.set_index('group').sum(level=0)
```

---

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
group,amount
x,12
x,345
x,3
y,1
y,45
z,14
x,4
x,52
y,54
z,23
z,235
z,21
y,57
y,3
z,87'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj)

dfout = (df.sort_values(by='amount', ascending=False)
         .groupby('group')
         .nth([0,1,2])
         .sum(level=0)
         .reset_index())

print(dfout)
```

Returns:

```
  group  amount
0     x     409
1     y     156
2     z     345
```

Comment: @ScottBoston I figured it out. head() on groupby returns a dataframe without the groupby object as index. So we were missing the fact we should `set_index('group')`. Another alternative would be to use nth. Thanks for making me curious :)

Comment: Thank you @Anton vBR and Scott Boston for your time and providing information. I just wanted to know what will reset index do , and I looked at the outcome the ordering was different from what I had. Is that the use of reset_index ? to make sure that the previous ordering of rows is kept intact.

Comment: @Avi Do you want the mid-dataframe? Then you could do this for instance: `df.sort_values(by='amount', ascending=False).groupby('group').head(3).sort_index()`. The `reset_index()` in the end is just moving out the group column from index to a column as it looked like something you might want.